# $A$-algebra B and $Hom_{A}(B,A)$ and their rank.

Tags: modules

Let $A$ and $B$ be a commutative ring and $B$ an $A$-module, and suppose that $B$ is finitely generated and free as an $A$-module. Is $Hom_{A}(B,A)$ free over $A$ with the same rank as B?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is that hom as A-modules or A-algebras?

Comment: @DanielMcLaury $\text{Hom}_{A-alg}$ isn't an A-module--adding ring maps often isn't a ring map. For a concrete example, it's a common fact that if $L/K$ is separable of degree $n$, then $\text{Hom}_{K-alg}(L,\overline{K})$ is of size $n$--and so clearly not a $K$-module for any infinite field $K$.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't even think about that.  I was just wondering why he gave $B$ a ring structure since it doesn't seem to come up in the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Hint: What if you considered the map $\text{Hom}_A(A^n,A)\cong A^n$ by the map $f\mapsto (f(e_1),\ldots,f(e_n))$ where $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ is a basis for $A^n$.

Also useful is the fact that the same statement is true if all instances of "free" are replaced with "projective". Then you merely note that if $P\oplus C=A^n$ then by the above, and the fact that $\text{Hom}_A$ is additive, you get that $\text{Hom}_A(P,A)\oplus\text{Hom}_A(C,A)\cong A^n$. Thus, $\text{Hom}_A(P,A)$ is also f.g. projective.

Comment: I thought that $(f_{i})_{i=1,2,...,n}$ such that $f_{i}(a_{1}e_{1}+\dots +a_{n}e_{n})=a_{i}$ is a basis for $Hom_{A}(A^n,A)$ but the unit element is not preserved by $f_{i}$ unless $1=e_{1}+\dots +e_{n}$. Is there always exits such a basis?

Comment: @user53216 Did you see the above discussion in the comments? Did you mean A-algebra homomorphisms?

Comment: The book I'm now reading says "The $A$-module $Hom_{A}(B,A)$ is ...".

Comment: @user53216 Then it certainly means A-module homomorphisms. In that case, module maps needn't preserve unit.

Comment: I understand. Thanks!